# Parsing tensorflow graph node by node to print inputs

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

How do I parse tensorflow .pb file node by node? I want to print attribute and input values for each node of the node in a graph.
I am using TF 1.13.

Comment: Do you mean for every graph operation you would like to print its parameters and name of the input nodes? Also, which TF version are you using?

Comment: Yes. I am using tf1.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read the graph [using](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8854):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_filename ='PATH_TO_PB.pb'
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        g_in = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
LOGDIR='YOUR_LOG_LOCATION'
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR)
train_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

You can then list all the oprations as:

```
for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
    print(str(op.name), op.inputs)
```

To get further details about operation parameters you can look into `op.node_def` It might be not very structured.